# How to export file with nuget?

Tags: c#

I have a nuget package that uses the Apose.PDF package which I have a license for. The license is put in a separate file called Aspose.Total.lic and is located in the same folder The folder structure is like this.

```
Project
  -PDFReader.cs
  -Aspose.Total.lic
```

The PDFReader.cs has the following code to read the license:

```
    static PDFReader()
    {
        var license = new License();
        license.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");
    }
```

And all this works fine locally. But when I export my code to a Nuget package and use the package from another program, I get exceptions that it cannot find "Aspose.Total.lic" Copying the contents of the file and putting it as argument for SetLicense does not work, it expects a file. Now the question is, how and maybe where do I export the file when packing a nuget package? This is my nuspec file (some code is abbreviated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/10/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>XYZ</id>
    <version>1.3.7</version>
    <summary />
     <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Aspose.PDF" version="18.10.0" />
    </dependencies>
    <frameworkAssemblies>
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System" />
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName="System.Data" />
    </frameworkAssemblies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="XYZ\bin\Release\XYZ.dll" target="lib\net47\XYZ.dll" />
    <file src="XYZ\Aspose.Total.lic" target="lib\Aspose.Total.lic" />
  </files>
</package>
```

My guess here is the the target location is wrong for the file.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet exposes 3 folder automatically, `lib` for dlls, `tools` for powershell scripts and `content` for other content. (I think - it's been a while)

Try changing :

```
<files>
  <file src="XYZ\bin\Release\XYZ.dll" target="lib\net47\XYZ.dll" />
  <file src="XYZ\Aspose.Total.lic" target="lib\Aspose.Total.lic" />
</files>
```

To :

```
<files>
  <file src="XYZ\bin\Release\XYZ.dll" target="lib\net47\XYZ.dll" />
  <file src="XYZ\Aspose.Total.lic" target="content\Aspose.Total.lic" />
</files>
```

Comment: I just tried this, and if I unpack the nuget package, I can see the .lic file in the content folder. But I still get the error that it cannot find the license.

Comment: It might be on a slightly different path after installation or you might need to manually change the build action, you need to make sure on build/publish that the file is in a predictable location.

Comment: Are you using the old style `packages.config` or the new style `PackageReference` in the `.csproj` file. This answer is applies to the old style, it's slightly different in the new style.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should package that file as **content**. You can check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files) how to achive that.